# composer will not work with current setting PHP 7.1 / windows 10

Tags: installation, composer-php

windows 10 / php 7.1

running composer setup "https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows" I get an error.

composer will not work with current setting

1)
php 7.1 has 'C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll' and it is no longer has
'C:\php\ext\php_mysql.dll'

2)
imagick is installed and the file 'php_imagick.dll' is in the c:\php\ext folder

thanks for any help on this...

here is the full error

---

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

---

Comment: So, have you read the message that was given? PHP 7 has no `php_mysql.dll`, so you should not reference it

Comment: as it turns out, if you comment out the imagick line in php.ini the composer installs fine; after install of composer just un comment the imagick line; i guess the composer install does not like the imagick in there; i also removed the reference to php_mysql.dll;